# Determine when a file has been dragged out of the window - Safari 6 OS X

Tags: javascript, html, safari, osx-mountain-lion

I'm currently able to determine when the user has dragged a file out of the browser window in every other browser, other than Safari on OS X.  All other browsers seem to provide some cues in the dragleave event.  For example, in Chrome, event.clientX and event.clientY are set to 0.  In Firefox, event.relatedTarget is null.  However, no such clues seem to exist in Safari on OS X.  Does anyone have any idea how I can can determine when a user has dragged a file out of the browser window (after dragging it into the window) on this browser?

Comment: So, if the coordinates are not 0, what are they, when drug outside the window?

Comment: Some non-0 value.  It appears as if the value doesn't change after dragging out of the window.